# Add new record with form in wpf

Tags: wpf

Yesterday I posted a question how I could validate a form WITHOUT the forms datacontext set to an object.

"It is the equivalent of monkeys juggling with grenades" I read in a comment.

Right. So. I want to get it straight how it works then. Lets say I have a simple form with two textboxes and a button to submit the data in the form. Let's say I am filling in stuff about a product. But how can I set the datacontext to something that doesn't exist yet? And how can I validate the textboxes for not being empty with that?

Answer (score 0):

> There's a 1000 ways to skin a cat

For Button & TextBoxes.  You could bind the IsEnabled of the button to the Length of the Text.Length with a converter.  This way the user wouldn't be able to save anything without typing something in.

For the DataContext: Do you really need one?  Are you creating a UserControl that will be used elsewhere?  Put everything in the codebehind if you need to.  If you need a DataContext, create an empty one, it's a simple POCO object.

Comment: :-) Yesterday I was looking for something you suggested, the topic was called something like "validating fields WITHOUT datacontext", and there were some people that said that it better be done WITH a datacontext, and one of them gave me the monkey phrase.